# Get argument from registry C#

Tags: c#, winforms, arguments, registry

I'm set key value in registry as follows-

```
 RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
                ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);


  registryKey.SetValue("MobiCheckerTest", Application.ExecutablePath + "%autostart");
```

Registry looks like-

```
C:\Users\skpaul\Desktop\StartupApp\StartupApp\bin\Debug\StartupApp.EXE%autostart
```

In Program.cs

```
 static void Main(string[] args) //args= string[0].
    {
        Program.LaunchedViaStartup = args != null && args.Any(arg => arg.Equals("autostart", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

Form1.cs

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MessageBox.Show(this, string.Format("Lanched Via Startup Arg:{0}", Program.LaunchedViaStartup));
    }
```

Argument can not be read in program.cs.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using a percent (%) sign?  Try a [space] instead:

```
registryKey.SetValue("MobiCheckerTest", "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath + "\" autostart");
```